# How to detect instances where code accidentally creates a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

In doing some wholesale refactoring, I've come across instances where I've made the same mistake.  I have accidentally passed a pointer to a pointer instead of just the pointer.

Code explains it best. Look for the `/* oops */` below.

The struct:

```
struct my_struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int value;
}
```

Initialize function:

```
void initialize(struct my_struct *s)
{
    s->x = 0;
    s->y = 0;
    s->z = 0;
    s->value = 0;
}
```

The original function:

```
struct my_struct do_something()
{
    struct my_struct s;

    initialize(&s);

    s.value = 27;

    return s;
}
```

The new function

```
void do_something(struct my_struct *s)
{
    initialize(&s); /* oops! */

    s->value = 27;
}
```

It should have been:

```
void do_something(struct my_struct *s)
{
    initialize(s); /* fixed */

    s->value = 27;
}
```

Is there a way, maybe a compiler flag or a linter that can help me locate these oopsies?

**NOTES:**
I'm using gcc (but if another compiler or linter can find this, please tell)

I'm using these compiler flags and they don't catch it:

```
CFLAGS = \
    -std=c89 \
    -pedantic \
    -pedantic-errors \
    -Werror \
    -Wextra \
    -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wall \
    -Wold-style-definition \
    -Wdeclaration-after-statement \
    -Wundef \
    -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-qual \
    -Wcast-align \
    -Wfloat-equal \
    -Wno-missing-braces
```

I have prototypes in a header for everything.

It's not the standard I picked -- C90. C99 and C11 all take it too.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.1.1 20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3)
```

Comment: If you use prototypes rather than K&R old-style function declarations, the compiler is obligated to issue a diagnostic if you pass an incorrect pointer-type.

Comment: @LPs , nope, it's okay. Returning a `struct` copies the data (like returning an `int`).

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and listen to it.

Comment: @MikeCAT I've got alot of them turned on and nothing so far.  Any one in particular you think will catch this?

Comment: Passing a pointer to pointer to a function expecting a single pointer should emit a warning with `-Wall -pedantic` flags on, or are you passing to a function expecting a `void *`?

Comment: @Myst My bad. I cancelled

Comment: What is the prototype of `initialize()`? What kind of pointer does it take? `struct my_struct *` or `void *`?

Comment: What? And you're *not* getting a warning? Is your GCC ancient?

Comment: Ah ... wait. Why do you live 27 years in the past? (C89)

Comment: @Daniel Jour -- nope - C99 takes it too.

Comment: If the prototype for `initialize()` is visible at the point it is called, and the argument passed to it cannot be converted to the type of the parameter as if by conversion, the compiler *must* issue a diagnostic message. If your compiler doesn't, file a bug report.

Comment: The option is `-Wincompatible-pointer-types`, and should be included in `-Wall`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @Groo.  That was it.  A stupid mistake was causing that warning from not firing.  It's showing the error now

Comment: @010110110101 Can you share the mistake that caused this? I think this could be useful information for future readers.

Comment: @LPs, it wasn't a "bad", you might have known about `struct` return behavior, but future readers might not. Mistakes get the knowledge out there, which is good for future readers :)

Comment: It looks like a misuse of C, that is some kind of undefined behavior. Shared names should be declared the same, so practically should be declared in a single *common* header file suitably included in every compilation unit using these names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a pointer to a pointer where only a pointer is expected must cause a compiler error. Thus I cannot reproduce what your example is suggesting (GCC 5.4.0, C99).

But there is a situation that can cause this kind of error:

foo.h:

```
struct foo {
  int dummy;
};
```

main.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
void init(void *);
int main() {
  struct foo f;
  struct foo * fp = &f;
  init(&f);
  init(&fp);
  return 0;
}
```

init.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
// Need a prototype because otherwise -Wmissing-prototypes issues a warning
// Such code is not that uncommon, though, especially when e.g. there
// are C preprocessor macros that help defining some kinds of functions.
void init(struct foo *f);
void init(struct foo *f) {
  f->dummy = 42;
}
```

This compiles fine without any warning. The translation unit `main.c` sees the (wrong) declaration `void init(void *)` and thus emits no warning when passing different pointer types (as they're all implicitly convertible to `void *`). Since C compilers usually don't mangle parameter types into the symbols of the resulting object files, the linker will happily resolve the reference to the function `init` from `main.o` with the function symbol `init` in `init.o`.

```
[nix-shell:/tmp/wtf]$ nm init.o 
0000000000000000 T init
[nix-shell:/tmp/wtf]$ nm main.o 
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U init
0000000000000000 T main
                 U __stack_chk_fail
```

C++ compilers *do* mangle parameter types into the symbols, thus:

```
[nix-shell:/tmp/wtf]$ LANG= g++ -Wall -Wextra main.c init.c 
/run/user/1000/cctWt0Nl.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x1d): undefined reference to `init(void*)'
main.c:(.text.startup+0x27): undefined reference to `init(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*Note: I'm **not** suggesting to compile your C code with a C++ compiler. Don't do that, please.*

Comment: But using different signatures in the header and in the unit must emit a warning too, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann Only if all translation units actually include that header with the signature.

Comment: `init.c:2:6: warning: no previous prototype for ‘init’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]`

Comment: @AlterMann True, though I've seen (mostly legacy) code doing what I added in my edit...

Comment: Yes, after your last edit it compiles without warnings